# First Add-on, lauch a pop up to an external app, passing selected items/s

Tags: gui-extensions, add-on

We are developing our first add-on and have been reviewing all the RWS examples. Very helpful, by the way.

We have a case for which we haven't found an example. We want to add a contextual menu to selected component(s) or folder(s). The menu will be called "Open Popup". So far, no doubts.

The action we want is to open a popup with the content (https://127.0.0.1/app/popup.asp?**items=tcm1,tcm2,tcm3**)

In other words, an external resource passing the selected items as parameters.

(context: Tridion 10, new GUI extension)

Can someone give us a hint? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your challenge consists of three parts:

1. getting list of selected items in the explorer table
2. adding custom action and render it in Context Menu
3. render Modal window with `iframe`

Our example might help you to cover first 2 points. Here is the link to extension action that shows how to perform action on selected items:
https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples/blob/main/sites-10-ux-update/content-explorer/copy-schema-item-ids-action-addon/copy-schema-item-ids-action/

On line #17 of [useCopySchemaItemIdsToClipboard.tsx](https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples/blob/main/sites-10-ux-update/content-explorer/copy-schema-item-ids-action-addon/copy-schema-item-ids-action/src/copySchemaItemIdsToClipboardAction/useCopySchemaItemIdsToClipboard.tsx) you can see how selection can be accessed from the Content Explorer context.

As for the #3, with current version of API it's not possible to use built-in modal window from the extension which would be preferable.

You can still try to achieve it, there are 4 ways that I can think of:

1. instead of modal window with `iframe` use separate window (`window.open()`);
2. use insight panel endpoint to render your `iframe`;
3. you can also try using any other endpoint which allows to render components for mounting modal component and then trigger open\close state from your action hook;
4. inject your custom Modal window into the DOM (`document`);

Meanwhile we will consider adding such possibility into API.
Thank you!

Comment: +1, great answer, Yevhen and glad to have you on Tridion Stack Exchange! :-D

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Yevhen Kifiak. I will do the window.open() approach!